# Switch home page language

Tags: magento, magento2, translation

i've setted evrything to create a new hompage in another language(in Magento 2.3), but when i go to frontend doesn't show the choice to selected "spanish hompage". someone could help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFAvG.png)

Comment: try this way https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/98307/49715

Answer (score 0):

You have to create new store view and assign your home page to this store view. Check the screenshots
[Create Store View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FukX.png)

[Go to: Stores-> Configurations-> General-> Web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R1PH.png)

[Change CMS Home Page under Default Pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1RMz.png)

Answer (score 0):

thank you, but i've alredy done it! i have setted a store view, than in store configuration (spanish store view) i've setted cms default home page and selected spanish home, but it doesn't show this option in the frontend!!